# Erase bytes in file in C++

Tags: c++

Can I erase last byte or bytes in file without creating new file and changing names?

For example, file contains "00 00 AB" and i need erase "AB". At the end, file contains only "00 00".

Comment: If it's just at the end, there might be an OS function to truncate.

Comment: Not in standard C++.

Comment: If the bytes are at the end, truncate the file. If they are anywhere else; read the file into memory, delete what you want, write a new temporary file and then rename it to the original name (overwriting it).

Answer (score 2):

Since C++17 we have the file system library that allows

```
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
  std::filesystem::path p("somefile");

  auto size = std::filesystem::file_size(p);
  std::filesystem::resize_file(p, size - 1);
}
```

If the new size is larger than the old, the file will be filled with zero-bytes, otherwise it's truncated.

Answer (score 2):

It resizes file to 2 byte from any size and truncates remain data.
"00 00 AB" -> "00 00"

```
#include <filesystem>
int main(){
    std::filesystem::resize_file("test.dat", 2);
}
```